# Angular JS app not building properly on Grunt Compile,(minification) works fine on Grunt watch/build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification, minify

I am trying to compile my application that uses Angular JS (ngbp boilerplate). I'm very new to Angular and the SPA concept. It is a relatively simple app, that is setup to be built by Grunt. 
The issue is weird - when I do a grunt watch, the application builds fine and everything works perfectly. But if I do a grunt compile, some of the stuff in the app don't work.

For example, some URLs to child modules using states use `ui-router` do not load. There are no errors on the console. My controllers all have inline dependency injection

eg.`controller( 'app.subModule', ['$scope','localStorageService','$http','$rootScope','$stateParams', function($scope,localStorageService,$http,$rootScope,$stateParams) {.......})]);`

Is there any other known issue caused by minification?

EDIT: I did some debugging and it looks like only this particular module is not working upon minification. The rest of the modules are loading fine. The code for the module is:

http://pastebin.com/6L0pR4bQ

EDIT2: I tried using ngmin as advised, but that doesn't seem to be resolving the issue. It is only this module that fails to load. All others are loading fine. So I feel that the issue is in the code for this module. I also tried manually annotating the functions, as can be seen from the pastebin code paste.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your paths and if all files are included? I assume grunt make bundle for you from all scripts in compile process

Comment: Yes, grunt makes the bundle from all of my scripts. So all my files are included. The weird part is, grunt build seems to be working and compile was also working up until a day ago. Now, it is just this module that is not loading. Can't seem to figure out why...

Comment: Can you provide any errors youa re getting that can lead us to solution

Comment: I unfortunately am not getting any errors. When I click on my link, it just defaults to the fallback URL, instead of transitioning into the new state. I tried ngmin. Doesn't seem to resolve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem that can be with minification is DI annotations for functions  - before minification all functions with dependency injection should be annotated manually. It is not only about controllers - also module `run` and `config`, directives, services, filtes...

When using grunt for most cases this can be done automatically using [grunt-ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin).

If you need a good example ho to configure all this - take a look at [yeoman/generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)

---

You need annotate your resolves for states - because they are not automatically annotated by ngmin. You have: `validState` and `pmGetPlan` without annotations.

Because resolves was not annotated ui-router fails to load state and by default it is silent about this...

You can add event handler for this on `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
 function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
   console.log('$stateChangeError', event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error);
});
```

Comment: grunt-ngmin is an excellent solution, i think it even add inline DI where needed

Comment: I tried ngmin. Added to my gruntfile. Doesn't seem to be resolving the issue. My compile task on grunt has the following:

grunt.registerTask( 'compile', [
    'less:compile', 'copy:compile_assets', 'ngmin', 'concat:compile_js', 'uglify', 'index:compile'
  ]);

When I run grunt compile, it shows the ngmin ification, but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @imguru you can try to run your build script excluding `uglify` task, then if it is issue of missing annotation you will get working app, and you would be able to look on you problematic module and search for not annotated functions.

Comment: @BogdanSavluk - I tried that and the app works fine. So the issue occurs during the uglyfication. So the assumption that the issue was with this particular module (subModule.js) seems to be right. Is there another approach to fix the annotation issue other than ngmin? It seems to be not working. I even tried manually annotating every function. Is there any other possibility other than this annotation issue?

Comment: @imguru can you post whole subModule.js with annotations done by hand somewhere on pastebin or something like?

Comment: @BogdanSavluk, thanks so much! I've added the annotations .. please find the code here http://pastebin.com/BSe3FFxZ. Minification's still not working though. Could you let me know if you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Correction.. the code works now! Thank you very much. You saved me a couple of days of work!!